# Can't get rid of custom styles in an Excel 2013 workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I use Excel 2013 and I am trying to clean up an 8000 KB spreadsheet which has evolved over the years to include thousands of duplicate cell styles.

I managed to get rid of most of them using some VBA code, as in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585882/having-trouble-deleting-custom-styles-in-excel-2016).  However, I am now stuck with three custom styles which I can't seem to get rid of by any obvious means:

[image]

**Does anyone have any ideas on how to get rid of those last three custom styles?**

Right-clicking and deleting doesn't work, and neither does any of the obvious VBA code such as the one in the linked question.

Comment: It's rare kind of problem that VBA codes are not working,, possibly you have changed the security level or MACROS are disabled,, better share the Workbook on cloud so that it can be fixed!!